# How does Wine generate the image files for a Start Menu entry?

Tags: wine, icons

With an eye toward extracting all of the sizes of an icon (ICO file) as PNG images [from an EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36808585/393280), I noticed that Wine appears to do this automatically.

After the installation of [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/), Wine (I presume) had created a Desktop Entry at `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/foobar2000.desktop`, containing the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=foobar2000
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix "$HOME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/foobar2000.lnk"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=Play, organize and tag your music.
Path=$HOME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/foobar2000
Icon=3C17_foobar2000.0
```

Eventually, the `Icon` key caught my eye, and I discovered that it resolved according to [the Icon Theme Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec). Hunting around, I found the directories `~/local/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/` which contained the files for these icons (each folder containing `3C17_foobar2000.0.png`), again which I presume Wine created.

My question is how did Wine generate these image files from the application (or shortcut file)?

Comment: I think this is really a "how does the [Portable Executable file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) work" question (or maybe a programming/library one?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wine includes a [`winemenubuilder`](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/programs/winemenubuilder/winemenubuilder.c) program which takes care of this: it takes a Windows shortcut, and creates a matching FDO (FreeDesktop.Org) `.desktop` file. Icon extraction is part of this, handled by the `open_module_icon` and related functions. To extract icons, `winemenubuilder` finds the executable corresponding to the shortcut (optionally waiting for it to be created, if necessary), and loads the resources it contains using Wine’s `LoadResource` function, finds the icons, and converts them to an appropriate image format.

```
wine winemenubuilder /path/to/link.lnk
```

will convert the link to a `.desktop` file, in `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs`, and extract the available icons, convert them, and store them in the appropriate subdirectories of `~/.local/share/icons`. (I think `/path/to/link.lnk` has to be accessible using Wine’s drive mappings; it works well with `.lnk` files which have been installed in Wine.)

```
wine winemenubuilder -t /path/to/link.lnk /path/to/icon.png
```

will extract the first icon in the executable pointed at by `link.lnk` to `icon.png`.

Comment: For some reason I get an error message: Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.

Comment: I think I found the root-cause. When creating a wine 64-bit bottle, the `winemenubuilder` executable is not working.